# SQL Server Pivot Table with Counts and Sums

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I am trying to get an SQL Server Pivot table to work that allows me to count and then sum a number of columns (6 in total). The purpose of the pivot table is to aggregate online questionnaire results for any number of production sites. There are 6 questions which can have 3 result values - Target, Action and Fail. What I am trying to do is count up the number of Target, Action and Fail for each question, and to then sum this up for each. So, for example, Production Site A could have 2 Target, 2 Action and 2 Fail.

My understanding is that the SQL Server Pivot table could deliver this information, which can then be display in ASP.Net ReportViewer. Below is my code, but it is not working, and could do with some expert help:

```
     SELECT PRODUCTION_Site,
     [Target],
     [Action],
     [Fail]
     FROM
     (SELECT Production_Site,
             SUM(Coding),
             SUM(Measurable),
             SUM(Appearance),
             SUM(Aroma),
             SUM(Flavour),
             SUM(Texture)
               FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
               GROUP BY Production_Site) AS T
          PIVOT
         (
           COUNT(Coding) FOR Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding IN ([Target],[Action],[Fail])
           COUNT(Measurable) FOR Grocery_Measurable IN ([Target],[Action],[Fail])
           COUNT(Appearance) FOR Grocery_Appearance IN ([Target],[Action],[Fail])
           COUNT(Aroma) FOR Grocery_Aroma IN ([Target],[Action],[Fail])
           COUNT(Flavour) FOR Grocery_Flavour IN ([Target],[Action],[Fail])
           COUNT(Texture) FOR Grocery_Texture IN ([Target],[Action],[Fail])) AS P
```

Is there a way round this, or is Pivot table not the solution?

Table is

```
Production_Site,
Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding,
Grocery_Measurable,
Grocery_Appearance,
Grocery_Aroma,
Grocery_Flavour,
Grocery_Texture
```

Data in the table would like this:

```
Site A, Target, Action, Fail, Target, Target, Target
Site B, Target, Action, Fail, Target, Target, Target
Site C, Target, Target, Target, Target, Target, Target
Site A, Target, Target, Target, Target, Target, Target
```

The result I am looking for is

```
Production_Site | Target | Action | Fail
Site A              10       1       1
Site B               4       1       1
Site C               6       0       0
```

Comment: can you provide the table structure, some sample data and then the desired result of the `PIVOT`?

Comment: I keep this to the main data - check original question for details

Comment: What does not work? Can you setup a SQL Fiddle example?

Comment: Just added some table structure, data and an example of the result I am trying to acheive

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A much easier way to perform this query would be to apply both the `UNPIVOT` and then the `PIVOT` functions:

```
select *
from
(
  select Production_Site, value 
  from t_Pqe_Grocery
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding, Grocery_Measurable,
                Grocery_Appearance, Grocery_Aroma, 
                Grocery_Flavour, Grocery_Texture)
  ) unp
) src
pivot
(
  count(value)
  for value in ([Target], [Action], [Fail])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd888/4)

The `UNPIVOT` takes your column list and transform it into multiple rows which makes it much easier to count:

```
select Production_Site, value 
from t_Pqe_Grocery
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding, Grocery_Measurable,
              Grocery_Appearance, Grocery_Aroma, 
              Grocery_Flavour, Grocery_Texture)
) unp
```

Unpivot Result:

```
| PRODUCTION_SITE |  VALUE |
----------------------------
|          Site A | Target |
|          Site A | Action |
|          Site A |   Fail |
|          Site A | Target |
|          Site A | Target |
|          Site A | Target |
|          Site B | Target |
|          Site B | Action |
|          Site B |   Fail |
|          Site B | Target |
|          Site B | Target |
|          Site B | Target |
|          Site C | Target |
|          Site C | Target |
|          Site C | Target |
|          Site C | Target |
|          Site C | Target |
|          Site C | Target |
|          Site A | Target |
|          Site A | Target |
|          Site A | Target |
|          Site A | Target |
|          Site A | Target |
|          Site A | Target |
```

Then applying the `PIVOT` to this will get the count that you want for each of the `PRODUCTION_SITE`s. After adding the `PIVOT` the result is:

```
| PRODUCTION_SITE | TARGET | ACTION | FAIL |
--------------------------------------------
|          Site A |     10 |      1 |    1 |
|          Site B |      4 |      1 |    1 |
|          Site C |      6 |      0 |    0 |
```

Comment: Thank you, but one last question is it possible for example to add a where clause to the pivot if a user wants to look at say 3 sites rather than all sites over a time period?

Comment: @Andy5 yes, you can still apply a `WHERE` clause to limit any of the results - similar to this -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd888/23 -- you can even apply a `WHERE` clause to the inner `UNPIVOT` query