# T-SQL: Rows to Columns With Count

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Let me draw up the table first (there are dozens of columns and dozens of values under `Code` in reality)

```
Code | Pat   | Col1 | Col2 | Col3
---------------------------------
ABC  | 001   |      | XX   | Q1
ABC  | 002   | xx   | xx   | Q1
ABC  | 003   | xx   | xxx  | Q1
DEF  | 004   | xx   | xx   | Q1
DEF  | 005   | xx   | xx   | Q1
DEF  | 006   | xx   | xxx  | Q1
```

The resulting table need to look like

```
ABC | DEF
---------
2   | 3
3   | 3
```

Let me try and explain. For each '`Code`' column, I would need to count the number of entries in `Col1` to `ColX` where the cell is not null/empty.

So in example above, Code `ABC` has a count of 2 in `Col1` and a count of 3 in `Col2` Similarly for `DEF`, both have a count of 3

I've tried lots of things but got to the point where I'm now looking at a blank page again!

**ALTERNATIVELY**

```
Code | Col1 | Col2
--------------------
ABC  | 2    | 3   
DEF  | 3    | 3
```

Please advise

Comment: Do you know all Code-Entries when you write the query?

Comment: There's 81 of them in total and it's likely to go up or down

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415540/sql-server-pivot-table-with-counts-and-sums

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution can be reached by using `GROUP BY` and summing up a calculated number:

```
SELECT 
    [Code], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(Col1, '') = '' THEN  0 ELSE 1 END) as [Col1], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(Col2, '') = '' THEN  0 ELSE 1 END) as [Col2], 
    ...
FROM T 
GROUP by [Code]
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tag that we are on 2008 R2 so this doesn't work

Comment: moved from `IIF` to `CASE`